# How can I build a haskell '#' mountain?

Tags: haskell

> Define a function called mountain that draws a mountain of height n and width that can be climbed from the east (right). Widen the mountain from top to bottom by one character per line. The mountain should consist of '#' characters, with the different levels of the mountain separated by the newline character. No more new line characters at the end of the mountain. A mountain with a negative height should be equal to a height of 0, so in this case the result should be an empty list.

> Do you have any idea what I could write in the otherwise case ?

```
mountain :: Int -> String
mountain a 
 | a < 1 = ""
 | a == 1 = "#"
 | a == 2 == "#\n##"
 | otherwise = ???
```

Comment: A mountain 2 is just a mountain 1 with ## under it. A mountain 3 is just a mountain 2 with ### under it. See any pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with an accumulator: a variable that contains the number of `#` characters you need to write, and then makes a recursive call for these items.

The `mountain` function then looks like:

```
mountain :: Int -> String
mountain n = go 1
    where go i 
              |  i <= n = … ++ go (i+1)
              | otherwise = …
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts.

A more elegant approach might be to use `map` where we create a list from `1` to `n`, and each time map on a string for that line, and then use [**`unlines :: [String] -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines) to join these strings together:

```
mountain :: Int -> String
mountain = unlines (map (…) [1 .. n])
```